# WebDriver : Select Radio group based on Option value

Tags: webdriver, radio-group

Am trying to select an option from a RadioGroup by giving the below command using WebDriver

**driver.findElement(By.name("selectedAdvertiser value=4_7")).click();**

Above piece of code was exported from IDE.But it throws an ElementNotFoundException.
fyi: Its a radio group with multiple options. My requirement is to select the option based on the input.

Comment: Can you use a developer tool like fire bug and find the HTML code of the Radio Group. Its very difficult to find a solution with the details you have provided

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of the "value=4_7".  You are doing a By.name, so only the name should be present which is probably just "selectedAdvertiser".  If you need the value=4_7 to identify the button you are clicking because all the radio buttons have the same name, try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='selectedAdvertiser'][value='4_7']").click();
```